# Is using CDN of any library is more suitable rather then downloading in our local system or servers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cdn, developer-tools

Recently someone told me that using a CDN link can actually speed up a website is it true? And if this is true then on which condition we should import libraries in our system

Comment: From the perspective of a user, a CDN will have endpoints in various places around the world which may be faster for users to access than your server

Comment: When you feel your individual server(s) can beat the multiple global servers the CDN is hosted on. Also, when you want to avoid situations like what happened last month when a CDN outage took out a lot of popular websites https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2021-06-08/explaining-cdns-and-why-big-websites-crash-together-quicktake

Comment: Here you can find huge amount of information [What is Better CDN or Local File](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/92083/local-files-vs-cdn)

Comment: Obviously there is a trust factor invovled, do you trust the CDN you are using to run random scripts on your website. Also, there might be countries blocking few CDNs. So the location of your target audience matters a lot.

Comment: Practically (just did a small test), a 12.6 KB file took `300-310ms` from one of my VMs while it took only somewhere around `200ms` with a CDN. There are lots of factors for sure but using a CDN speeds of things...

Answer (score 1):

**The benefits of how CDN works**

> There are a ton of benefits when you use CDN. such as:

1. **Performance**
2. **Lower costs**
3. **Scalability**